# Automation Studio: "Automation runtime target mismatch. The target online does not match." error

Tags: plc, br-automation-studio

When transferring the project to the PLC, the dialog displays "Automation runtime target mismatch. The target online does not match."

How do I get past this error?

B&R Automation Studio version: 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to realize I had the wrong plc plugged in.  Attempting to download a project that requires an X20CP0484 plc will not work when an APC3100 plc is connected.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly right, you found your issue.  That error is telling you the controller in your physical view and the controller you are online with have a different part number.

Comment: tkezy,   Thanks for the confirmation.   Your text may be better as a comment to FishJD's answer than to a standalone answer.  As a comment, they will stick together as other persons add answers.   Although, you may not have the prevligies to add a comment at this time.